# Why does element load with blank opacity? And why does my js cancel the hover effect?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an element which should fade out when clicked and fade back in when it's space is clicked again. Additionally, its opacity should be 0.9 (rather than 1) when visible.

There's two problems with my code. The hover selector seems to break as soon as I click the element and js executes. (Once it unfades the element loses its hover effect.) The second is really weird, but my js accounts for it: initially the element has opacity == "" for some reason! I think it might be because the hover effect is confusing the js as to what the actual value of the opacity should be.

```
function gitErDone(element){
  var op = element.style.opacity;
  if(op != 0){
    fade(element);
    return;
  } else if(op == "" || op == null){
    element.style.opacity = 1;
    gitErDone(element);
    return;
  } else {
    unfade(element);
    return;
  }
}

function fade(element) {
  //works fine :)
}

function unfade(element) {
  //works fine :)
}
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.sm-box{
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
    background-position:center !important;
  }
  .sm-box:hover{
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  }
```

And here is the element in its natural habitat:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sm-box"></div>
  <div class="sm-box"></div>
  <div class="sm-box"></div>
  <div id="elem" class="sm-box" onclick="gitErDone(this)"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

So yeah my js and css are not playing nice together. For some reason the js is pulling the element in with blank opacity, and breaking the hover opacity effect afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understand what you seek here:

You want your div in the nature with opacity 1.
When you hover over it, you want it to jump to opacity 0.9.
If you click it, it should fade away.
If you click it again it should fade in again.

First problem I see is that, probably, your hover css definition and js execution are not comunicating well, probably because hover is not an event on Javascript event model, so to your js code, once you click, the div has opacity 1.

To fix this I'd use mouseMove events to switch between opacity 1 and 0.9

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use onMouseOver and onMouseOut to make it work, but do you know why the opacity is initially blank?

Comment: For "blank" opacity do you mean 1 or 0? Your code only changes opacity on hovering and on clicking, so in the beginning, before you interact with the div, it should have opacity 1, if it has 0 I don't know why it is, maybe inherited style from an ancestor or other css selector not represented on code snippet? Use browser debugging tools to check it's styles on execution time.